# Comparing files in R using for loop when there is missing files in a series

Tags: r

I've used below code which successfully compares two text files and logs the difference in a log file using for loop. The file names are in series, for example, File_1, File_2 etc.. but when there is a missing file in the series, the code stops the execution with error - No such file or directory.

Then I've used if condition to check the file existence but I am getting a below-mentioned error.

Please help me to skip comparison for a nonexisting file.

**Code:**

```
for(i in 1:length){
  prod_file_res_name <- sprintf("path/Query_Prod_%s.txt", i)
  beta_file_res_name <- sprintf("path/Query_Beta_%s.txt", i)

 if (exists('prod_file_res_name' && 'beta_file_res_name')){
  res <- tools::Rdiff(prod_file_res_name, beta_file_res_name, Log = TRUE)

  if(res[2] != "character(0)"){
     write(toString(res[2]), file = "LogFile.txt",append=TRUE)
  }

  else{
    elsevar <- sprintf("No difference found between prod and beta responses for query %s", i)
    print(elsevar)
   }
 }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Error in "prod_file_res_name" && "beta_file_res_name" : 
  invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

Answer (score 1):

**exists** checks if the given R objects (only takes R objects as input --> this caused your first error) exist in your environment. You initiate the R objects *prod_file_res_name* and *beta_file_res_name* before you check if they exist, so the **exists** call will always return TRUE. What you are looking for is the **file.exists** function which checks if the file does exist in your working directory:

```
   file.exists(prod_file_res_name) && file.exists(beta_file_res_name)
```

The second error was caused by the R objects existing but not the files you want to check.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. What you explained is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since `exists()` looks up single objects (from Documentation):

> Is an Object Defined?
>
> Description
>
> Look for an R object of the given name and possibly return it

`'prod_file_res_name' && 'beta_file_res_name'` doesn't work.

Rewrite
 `exists("prod_file_res_name" && "beta_file_res_name")`

to:

`exists("prod_file_res_name") && exists("beta_file_res_name")`

Comment: Thanks for clearing this, I understood your point and I've rewritten the code but I'm getting No such file error. Though I've written else code to print if the file doesn't exist but it's not printing the statement instead of throwing an error. Could you please help on this as well?
`Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file '<Path>/F_Query_Prod_15.txt': No such file or directory`

Comment: Modified Code:
`for(i in 1:length){
  prod_file_res_name <- sprintf("path/Query_Prod_%s.txt", i)
  beta_file_res_name <- sprintf("path/Query_Beta_%s.txt", i)
  
 if (exists("prod_file_res_name") && exists("beta_file_res_name")) {
  res <- tools::Rdiff(prod_file_res_name, beta_file_res_name, Log = TRUE)
  
  if(res[2] != "character(0)"){
     write(toString(res[2]), file = "LogFile.txt",append=TRUE)
  }
  
  else{
    elsevar <- sprintf("No diff found between responses for query %s", i)
    print(elsevar)
   }
 }
 else if{
    print("There is no file to compare")
  }
}`

Comment: @squraishi check out FloSchmo 's answer, he is completly right. If you want to check if a file exists, take his solution. Your "new" error message is simple: the file doesn't exist, this is not a R mistake. So in your example it searches for a file in "<Path>/F_Query_Prod_15.txt", check if you got a path and a file named like this.

Comment: If I'm using `file.exists()` , I'm always going to the `else()` part. As the program is not finding the file itself.

`if (file.exists("prod_file_res_name") && files.exists("beta_file_res_name"))`

Comment: [1] 14
[1] "There is no such file to compare"
[1] 15
[1] "There is no such file to compare"
[1] 16
[1] "There is no such file to compare"
[1] 17
[1] "There is no such file to compare"